# Error al enviar audio guardado en una app a whatsapp

Tags: android, whatsapp

El código que estoy utilizando es:

```
String path= "android.resource://"+Principal.this.getPackageName()+"/raw/a.mp3"; 
Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
Intent compartiraudio = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
compartiraudio.setType("audio/*");
compartiraudio.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(compartiraudio, "Comparte un archivo de audio"));
```

No se que estoy haciendo mal pero el audio no se envía, se abre el menú de compartir por whatsapp pero al aceptar da error.

Comment: Presione este enlace para [edit] su pregunta y agregue la descripción de los errores que obtenga. vista además [lee el tour del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Bienvenido Isaac!, es importante veas los consejos de Mauricio, esto para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida en el sitio y obtengas la respuesta que necesitas, en el caso de Android, generalmente es valioso mostrar siempre que error muestra en el LogCat al generarse el error, saludos!.

Comment: El problema es que no da ningún error la aplicación en sí, no se cierra, simplemente el audio no se envia. En el log solo sale esto:
E/FA: Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled. See https://goo.gl/NAOOOI
I/MediaPlayer: [HSM] stayAwake false uid: 10252, pid: 30198
I/MediaPlayer: Pid:30198 MediaPlayer destructor
I/MediaPlayer: setDataSource(124, 12390032, 95239)
I/MediaPlayer: [HSM] stayAwake true uid: 10252, pid: 30198
I/MediaPlayer: Pid:30198 MediaPlayer::start
I/MediaPlayer: [HSM] stayAwake false uid: 10252, pid: 30198 
Y creo que solo tiene que ver con la publicidad.

Comment: @IssacRuiz Tienes que buscar donde mencione "Caused by", pero en este caso el error es que no puedes compartir en WhatsApp recursos directamente desde el directorio interno o desde los folders /raw o /assets. Por favor realiza el [tour]!.

Comment: Lo pudisteis solucionar. A mi me pasa lo mismo con un pdf. La app no da error ya que funciona perfectamente en los moviles que he probado menos en el mio que a la hora de darle a OK en whatsapp para compartir no lo envia y dice "Fallo al compartir.....", pero como he dicho en otros moviles si funciona. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

**Es importante saber que al tratar de enviar un archivo por medio de WhatsApp, este debe encontrarse en el directorio de almacenamiento externo, esto aplica para archivos de audio, imagenes, etc. Si no se encuentra en esta ubicación requerimos primeramente realizar una copia del archivo y guardarlo en el directorio de almacenamiento externo.**

Este es un ejemplo suponiendo tener un archivo .mp3  dentro de `/raw/jorgesys_sound.mp3`

Primeramente realizamos una copia del archivo almacenado dentro de `/raw`  y posteriormente configuramos el intent para enviar este tipo de archivo por medio de la aplicación Whatsapp:

[image]

This are the methods to use

```
  private void sendWhatsAppAudio(){
        try {
           //Copy file to external ExternalStorage.
           String mediaPath = copyFiletoExternalStorage(R.raw.jorgesys_sound, "jorgesys_sound.mp3");

           Intent shareMedia = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            //set WhatsApp application.
            shareMedia.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            shareMedia.setType("audio/*");
            //set path of media file in ExternalStorage.
            shareMedia.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(mediaPath));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareMedia, "Compartiendo archivo."));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Whatsapp no se encuentra instalado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private String copyFiletoExternalStorage(int resourceId, String resourceName){
        String pathSDCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/" + resourceName;
        try{
        InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        out = new FileOutputStream(pathSDCard);
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int read = 0;
        try {
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } finally {
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return  pathSDCard;
  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No olvides definir el permiso:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```